# Test "proxies"; good TDD or a code smell?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

When I write tests for certain types of objects, such as UI elements like Forms or UserControls, I often find myself altering my TDD pattern; instead of going test-first, I define and lay out the form's controls, to provide a "skeleton", then start writing behavioral tests (databinding/"unbinding", display-mode behavior, etc). In doing so, I find myself dealing with non-public members. I also run into the same concern with other behavioral methods; I may want to focus on and exercise logic in some private helper called by another method, before worrying about the usage in the other method and its behavior.

To me, making everything public (and sometimes virtual) just to be able to unit-test everything is a smell; I don't want other objects being able to call a helper, or directly access a textbox; but I need to know that the helper does its job and the textbox gets its value when the form loads.

The solution I arrived at some time ago is to create a "test proxy" for the actual object under test. The proxy derives from the object under test, and doesn't hide or override any behavior, but it does provide internally-visible getters, setters and/or methods that make calls to non-public members of the object under test, allowing me to tell the object to perform certain actions of which I can then view the results, without requiring the test to also depend on proper integration within the object or making the method or some other member of interest public in production code just for testing purposes.

Advantages I see:

- Members' visibility is not determined by whether you want a unit test or not.
- Finer control over what you can do with the object in a test allows for more flexible and extensible testing.

Disadvantages I see:

- Class count increases, with an extra level to develop just for testing purposes.
- Care must be taken not to somehow end up using the test proxy in production code (making the constructor or the entire class internal generally does the trick)
- Not a "pure" unit test as you are, at some level, dependent on integration between the proxy and actual object under test.

The question is, is this a valid way to architect unit tests, or does the fact that I have to do this indicate a problem with the code or the testing strategy?

Comment: Is the "private helper" a method, or a class?  If it's a class, then its methods should be public and therefore testable from outside - that's great.  If it's a method, consider turning it into a class and thereby reducing to the previous case.

Comment: Good suggestion, but won't always work. As a more concrete example, a common pattern I picked up for forms is to implement a Bind() method whose job is to take some data object and populate the controls contained on the form or nested control. Such a method requires manipulating other non-public members (the nested controls), it only has value to the one form for which it was written, and it's one step in a series to properly initialize the form so I don't want it called directly by production code.

Comment: Am I missing something? In order to proxy your class do you not need to make its private members protected anyway? So your testing strategy is forcing you to make your members more accessible than you would like?

Comment: @David - Yes, that's another disadvantage, but protected's better than public for pointing consumers to the methods they should be using and the ones they shouldn't. The alternative is making everything I want to test public, which means making almost everything public, creating a maintenance nightmare as consumers plug in wherever they think they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction to this pattern is that you're de-emphasizing the 'D's in TDD. Your code is tested but those tests are not driving your design so the code you end up with has a different structure than it would if you had written tests first. A structure with more inaccessible private state than necessary. In general I'll argue that if you can't test your class' behavior using the public interfaces then you are either writing a test which doesn't make sense (testing implementation details) or you have a poorly designed public interface.

However if you're working with view classes this becomes a bit more complicated since you have "public" inputs and outputs via your view which you want to test but which are not necessarily exposed to the code using this view component. In that case I think it makes sense to give your tests access to that user interface; either by exposing those normally private attributes to the test (your proxy is one option and others may be available depending on the language you are using) or by writing some form of functional test which can drive the UI (again tools available depend on your environment).

Comment: +! for "you have a poorly designed public interface."

Comment: I like this answer best for it's "probably bad, but sometimes acceptable" which seems to be my situation; this is definitely a rarity in my tests, but sometimes there just isn't another good option.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it indicates a problem with your testing strategy or code.  The reason is because your violating encapsulation which is going to couple your tests to the implementation rather than the interface.  This will add to the overall work you do because refactors (for example) may no longer be free.

That being said I think there a good reasons to violate encapsulation, and they revolve around functions with side effects (which is often the case with UI programming).  In many cases you need to assure that functions are being called in a particular order or that they are called at all.  I think there are ways to mitigate how much you violate encapsulation.

If I'm writing tests for side effects I will usually separate them out into their own test.  I will also stub/mock out the side effect functions and assert they are called according to my requirements (ie, order, timing, called or not, arguments, etc).  This frees me from knowing the implementation details, but still allows me to assert that particular functions were called properly.

In certain languages it can be difficult to mock out the objects, or methods.  In those cases I will use dependency injection to pass the object or functions with side effects.  That way when testing I can pass my mocks for verification.

Answer (score 1):

MSTest uses this method to test private methods.  Visual Studio puts all the tests in a separate test project and creates an "Accessor" class.  That class is a subclass where all the private members are made public.  Since this subclass is in the test project it isn't available in the assembly under test.  I think this is a viable pattern for testing private methods and could be manually implemented in a TDD environment if you aren't using Visual Studio and MSTest.

Comment: +1 for reference to MS Accessor as a pattern. However note that OP and you are talking about unit tests, but not TDD